# jqGrid: how to change cell padding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid3.6.5 on google hosted jQueryUI1.8.2 and jQuery1.4.2

I want to change the cell padding of a jqGrid. For testing purposes I want to set it to 10px all around each cell.

The only option I've come across while googling is the following:

1. add padding with CSS. eg. `#grid-id td, #grid-id th { padding:10px; }`
2. set `cellLayout` option to 21  (paddingleft + paddingright + borderleft)

When I have no set width on any of the columns in my colModel, this works like expected. Though when I resize one of the headers, or set a column width in the colModel, headers and cells aren't aligned anymore.

Anyone know how to fix this or know an alternative way to alter cell padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution and am a bit ashamed of not finding it sooner :P

Apparently the grid headers ARE th's but not in the same table as the grid itself.
So by changing `#grid-id th {...}` to `body .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {...}` I got it to work as expected.

Comment: it si not enough to change only th style for some cases, for example for word wrapping, also you have to apply same style rules for wrapping on .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div..cheers

Answer (score 5):

Add a new CSS class to the columns that you need to style:

```js
$("#dataTable").jqGrid({

...

  colModel:[
    {name:"name",index:"name", width:600, align:"left", classes:"grid-col"},
    {name:"price",index:"price", width:100, align:"right", classes:"grid-col"}
  ],

...

});
```

Note `classes:"grid-col"` in this snippet.

Then style the columns with CSS using `!important` to give these rules the highest priority:

```
.grid-col {
  padding-right: 5px !important;
  padding-left: 5px !important;
}
```

It works for me in jqGrid 4.5.4 **with no column resizing problems**.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [jqGrid developer](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/modifying-the-td-cell-padding-on-a-jqgrid/), the `cellLayout` option is the preferred way. Unfortunately the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) is a bit cryptic:

> This option determines the padding + border width of the cell. Usually this should not be changed, but if custom changes to td element are made in the grid css file this will need to be changed. The initial value of 5 means paddingLef⇒2+paddingRight⇒2+borderLeft⇒1=5

Comment: This is what my question is based upon. (and what I can't get to work like expected)

Comment: Hmm... if this is what Tony (the developer) recommended then I don't know what else to tell you. You may need to modify jqGrid files in order to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing cellLayout out.  It solved a similar problem I was having.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar case by wrapping the content in each cell with a div which I in turn padded. It will give you a correct behavior since the column with stays fixed to your jqgrid configuration.

```
$("tr.jqgrow td").each(function(){
  $(this).wrapInner("<div class=\"cell\"/>")
})
```

And styled the div.cell like this (.sass).

```
table td .cell
  padding-left: 8px
  padding-right: 8px
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 tr.jqgrow td { padding: 0px 2px 0px !important; }
```

This will create cell-padding for both header and content cells.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to set the padding to the jqGrid th and `td` properly. This is my solution:

1.Override `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div` css class

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th div { padding: 10px; }
```

Do NOT add padding to the the `.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th` class.

2.After you have done the above, you can adding padding to the jqgrid data row.

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td{
     height: auto;
     white-space: normal;
     padding: 10px;
}
```